# Access local storage - mosysnc

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

i'm new with mobile apps development. Can anyone help me with mosync framework. I managed to do insert transaction into local storage but i really don't know how to retrieve the data from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't personally recommend anyone using MoSync for new projects anymore, since it hasn't been updated since March 2013 (the release of 3.3.1).

Also, you should probably ask in the official forum, but I think you're out of luck here: http://www.mosync.com/forum

This post also indicates that it doesn't simply work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102079/why-is-mosync-localstorage-not-working